# PHP Regex grab content from JSON vars

Tags: javascript, php, regex, json

I want to grab using preg_match some values from JSON vars, I have HTML and JSON vars stored in a PHP variable

```
"idAsc":"HDHX67","prenom":"Salah","nom":"Mounir","genre":"MASCULIN","civilite":"MR",
```

how can I grab for example Salah, or MR value from the string above

EDIT:

The string above contains also HTML content:

```
<script>

(function(){
.........
.........
"idAsc":"HDHX67","prenom":"Salah","nom":"Mounir","genre":"MASCULIN","civilite":"MR",
.....
```

Comment: Why don't you `json_parse` it? Assuming, of course, that you put the braces back on.

Comment: Why don't you use `json_decode` instead?

Comment: How about decoding the actual JSON string to an array (using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) with second parameter set as `TRUE`) and then accessing it? Trying to extract it with a regex is almost always a Bad Idea ™.

Comment: @Niet : the PHP var contains a full HTML document and I want to grab values from the JSON content

Comment: How is the json stored in the html? Sounds like you need to parse the html first and then get and parse the json.

Comment: @jeroen : can I use something like : /"prenom":"\w+"/ to get the value of prenom?

Comment: Blah, just realised I typed `json_parse` instead of `json_decode` XD Ah, the problems of working in JS and PHP at the same time, while tired and sick!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol : Thanks :) I solved it using : preg_match_all('/"prenom":"\w+"/i', $final_result, $result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this Regex Expression to get the JSON values I want :

```
preg_match_all('/"prenom":"\w+"/i', $str_source, $result);
```